# Django Rest Framework not creating table authtoken_token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to set up Django Rest Framework authtoken, From what I understand the table `authtoken_token` should be created after `makemigrations` and `migrate`. I added rest_framework to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Site',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'MySQLdb'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

The migration commands output:

```
'manage.py@MySite > makemigrations Site
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" makemigrations Site "C:/Users/Eric Franzen/PycharmProjects/MySite"
No changes detected in app 'Site'

Process finished with exit code 0
manage.py@MySite > migrate Site
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate Site "C:/Users/Eric Franzen/PycharmProjects/MySite"
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Site
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Process finished with exit code 0'
If anyone has any idea why the table is not being created the information would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks fine to me, are you sure you are looking at the correct database / that you have refreshed / that the tables are definitely not created?

Can you provide more information? What's the output of both commands?

Comment: The table was definitely not created, and I get No migrations to apply. and No changes detected when running the migration commands.

Comment: In that case please provide the output of the two management commands you ran.

Comment: I added them above, they don't give any errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

running `migrate authtoken` fixed this

Comment: Still didn't fix the problem

Comment: @enrique2334 I wonder why it didn't get migrated in the first place and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was using `migrate authtoken` due to a similar issue where the tables weren't being created.

But when running tests the migrations would fail, because of another migration on my app to store a Token on the superuser; `manage.py test` was not running the migrations in the order I needed.

The solution in my case was to add a dependency to my app's migration that needed Token, looking like:

```
dependencies = [
        ('api', '0005_auto_20200221_2108'), # the prior migration
        ('authtoken', '0002_auto_20160226_1747'), # the last authtoken migration I saw in showmigrations
    ]
```

After adding the dependency the migrations run successfully, including when I run test, and I can remove `migrate authtoken` from my workflow.

I'm not sure this solves the mystery of why the authtoken migrations weren't being run at all in the original scenario, but maybe it helps unstick someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just run the sql queries directly. I am using pgadmin.

Replace where necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE public.authtoken_token
(
    key character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT authtoken_token_pkey PRIMARY KEY (key),
    CONSTRAINT authtoken_token_user_id_key UNIQUE (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT authtoken_token_user_id_35299eff_fk_dashboard_dashboarduser_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.dashboard_dashboarduser (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.authtoken_token
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: authtoken_token_key_10f0b77e_like

-- DROP INDEX public.authtoken_token_key_10f0b77e_like;

CREATE INDEX authtoken_token_key_10f0b77e_like
    ON public.authtoken_token USING btree
    (key COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```