# Django migration didn't migrate authtoken and sessions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

When running `python manage.py migrate` not all migrations were run, specifically `django_celery_results`, `authtoken` and `sessions`. This resulted in the application related migrations erroring out.

[image: The terminal output looks like so:]

However, if I first manually migrate those three, and then specifically migrate `auth` (not sure why I'd need to migrate that again) and then do `python manage.py migrate` it'll work.

[image]

The installed apps on Django are like so:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_celery_results',
    'celery.contrib.testing.tasks',
    'api_app'
]
```

I'm wondering why that's happening, I thought `migrate` will run all the migrations listed in "operations to perform".

Comment: Related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982290/django-rest-framework-not-creating-table-authtoken-token

Comment: Please don't post screenshots errors. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: It would have run the migration for `authtoken` and `sessions` if the one for `api_app` hadn't failed first. If your `api_app` is dependent on the `authtoken` and `sessions` migrations, then you should add that dependency to your first migration, so that django knows which ones it should run first. Change your dependencies. Otherwise as you can see, for two non-related apps, it will run the migrations in alphabetical order. `admin__0001` is dependent on `auth__0001` that's why it ran that one first (but not yet the other `auth` migrations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `api_app.0002` migration creates a user without setting `last_login`. Therefore this migration must be run after the auth 0005 migration that allows nulls in this column.

If you add a [dependency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#dependencies) to your migration, then Django will run them in the correct order.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [('auth', '0005_alter_user_last_login_null')]
```